# Keyboard won't show after calling InputMethodManager.showSoftInput

Tags: android

I called the method this way:

```
getInputMethodManager().showSoftInput(view, 0, resultReceiver);
```

However, the keyboard doesn't show on my screen and resultReceiver doesn't receive a message in `onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData)`. The view is not null and `hasFocus() == true`.

Is there anyone know this issue? Thanks very much.

Thanks Karthik and Imen. I need to know the root cause why this method not working but not some workaround.

Updated on **2017/10/23**:

I debuged into android sdk source code and found that: a variable named `mServedView` is null and the method will return a `false`. However, the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#showSoftInput(android.view.View, int, android.os.ResultReceiver)) doesn't tell why or when this method will return a `false`.

Comment: Karthik, thanks for your answer but it doesn't fix my issue. In my case, I don't want to use `toggleSoftInput` instead of `showSoftInput` and I can't use the `InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED` since it is an util method. Flag need to be passed into this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

For displaying keyboard:

```
public void showSoftKeyboard(Context ctx, View v) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) ctx.getSystemService(
                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    }
```

For Hiding Keyboard:

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard(Context ctx, View v) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) ctx.getSystemService(
                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method :

```
 public void showSoftKeyboard(View aView) {
        if (aView != null) {
            aView.setFocusable(true);
            aView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            aView.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            keyboard.showSoftInput(aView, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: getSystemService() can't be called from out of nowhere. It hast to be called from a context.